# ionic 3 oneSignal.cancelNotification not working (Android Platform)

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, onesignal

Having implemented and working properly ionic native oneSignal and cordova oneSignal (Ionic 3, Android platform), when trying to cancel an specific notification with

```
this.oneSignal.cancelNotification(data.androidNotificationId)
```

the console shows a warning:

> vendor.js:67753 Native: tried calling OneSignal.cancelNotification,
>   but the OneSignal plugin is not installed;

and

> Install the OneSignal plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add
>   onesignal-cordova-plugin

It makes no sense since the plugin and notifications are working perfectly with the rest of methods, and this is the only method that doesn´t work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Requires Authentication Key**
>
> Requires your OneSignal App's REST API Key, available in Keys & IDs, unless the notification was created using include_player_ids and targeting only one user.

---

It is not implemented (in cordova). That's why it is not working.

Ionic native has give you the functions to call, but at this time there is no cordova / native (android / iOS) implementation behind this.

You need to do this from backend side.

Comment: I´ve checked it is not implemented in Cordova, you are right. The console warnings are wrong then. It has nothing to do with the Authentication Key (it is nedeed to implement oneSignal in general). No way to solve this problem from backend side, in my case (my requirements are client state dependents). Thanks